# How to get only one level of objects in s3 bucket in php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to find only top level object from S3 bucket?

If the key of the buckets are:

```
public/uploads/test_company/test1
public/uploads/test_company/test2
public/uploads/test_company/test1/test.txt
```

If want to find objects in:

```
public/uploads/test_company
```

then only

```
public/uploads/test_company/test1
public/uploads/test_company/test2
```

should come, not any subfolders and files. So how to do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify:

- `Prefix - 'public/uploads/test_company/'`
- `Delimiter = '/'`

The Prefix will limit results to only objects in that path.

The Delimiter tells S3 to treat the slash as a directory, so only objects *within* that directory will be returned. It will also provide a list of `CommonPrefixes`, which are the names of subdirectories.

From [AWS SDK for PHP 3.x: listobjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#listobjects):

```php
$result = $client->listObjects([
    'Bucket' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'Delimiter' => '<string>',
    'EncodingType' => 'url',
    'ExpectedBucketOwner' => '<string>',
    'Marker' => '<string>',
    'MaxKeys' => <integer>,
    'Prefix' => '<string>',
    'RequestPayer' => 'requester',
]);
```

Comment: PHP 3.x... from 2006!?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a PHP person, so I just did a general web search. Feel free to substitute with the current PHP version.

Comment: I am using php version 7.4

Comment: The above solution is not working.

Comment: It seems that the v3 label is the version of the SDK, not the version of PHP. When you say "above solution is not working", can you provide more details? What is coming back in the listing? You can also try it via the AWS CLI, eg: `aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --prefix public/uploads/test_company/ --delimiter '/'`